# New git repo from selected files in existing repo

Tags: git

I have a project under git control in which the code is organized into sub-directories for different parts of the project. Now I think that the contents of a particular sub-directory might be better off being an entirely different project of their own. Is it possible to cherry-pick files (or lets just say folders) from within this project and create a new git repository with those item while retaining all their existing commit history?

I am aware of the simpler option of just copying the entire project into a new project and deleting all the files and directories that i don't want and entering that as a new commit. But I wish to know if git has something of its own for doing this.

Comment: Maybe a branch? So you only edit that folder in your new branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) in order to extract a subfolder as its own repo.
See:

- [GitHub "Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository"](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)

  ```
  git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter YOUR_FOLDER_NAME master
  ```
- "[Atlassian "How to tear apart a repository: the Git way"](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/04/tear-apart-repository-git-way/)

Once you have a new repo for that subfolder, you can reference it back in your original repo, using [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: So this will only make the changes for the branch master, is that right?

Comment: @deepak yes. Make that in a fresh separate clone, for you to test.